How to reduce Normalized cosine similarty computation or run time?
I want to reduce the running time of this computation. Is there any way?
# **Cosine Similarity**
- $$ \text{cosine\_similarity}(u, w) = \frac{u \cdot w}{\|u\| \|w\|} $$

  $$ p_t(w|u) = \frac{ \text{cos}(u', w)}{\sum_{u_0 \in V} \text{cos}(u, w)} $$

Here is the Python code I am using:


def cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2):
    dot_product = np.dot(vec1, vec2)
    norm_vec1 = np.linalg.norm(vec1)
    norm_vec2 = np.linalg.norm(vec2)
    return dot_product / (norm_vec1 * norm_vec2)

# Compute translation probability using cosine similarity
def compute_translation_probability(target_word, candidate_word, word_embeddings):
    if target_word in word_embeddings and candidate_word in word_embeddings:
        target_vec = word_embeddings[target_word]
        candidate_vec = word_embeddings[candidate_word]

        # Calculate cosine similarity between target word and candidate word
        cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(target_vec, candidate_vec)
        
        # Calculate sum of cosine similarities between target word and all words in the embedding
        sum_cosine_similarities = sum(cosine_similarity(target_vec, word_embeddings[word]) for word in word_embeddings.index_to_key)

        # Return normalized cosine_sim
        if sum_cosine_similarities != 0:
            normalized_cosine_sim = cosine_sim / sum_cosine_similarities
            return normalized_cosine_sim
    
    return 0.0



Try running it in Spyder to determine which line is the bottleneck

Also note there exists sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity and scipy.spatial.distance.cosine

You should not be iterating over your word embeddings to compute sum_cosine_similarities.  You need to take advantage of numpy's vectorized operations to compute the cosine similarity of the target_vec against the entire array of word embeddings.
It looks like the word_embeddings is a dictionary with the values as numpy arrays.  We can create 2-d array of shape (n_words, embedding_size) and use that to perform all of the cosine similarity calculations at once.
import numpy as np


def cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2):
    dot_product = np.dot(vec1, vec2)
    norm_vec1 = np.linalg.norm(vec1)
    norm_vec2 = np.linalg.norm(vec2)
    return dot_product / (norm_vec1 * norm_vec2)


# Compute translation probability using cosine similarity
def compute_translation_probability(
    target_word: str, 
    candidate_word: str, 
    word_embeddings: dict[str, np.ndarray],
    ) -> float:
    """
    Calculates:
    p_t(w|u) = \frac{ \text{cos}(u', w)}{\sum_{u_0 \in V} \text{cos}(u, w)}
    """
    if (target_word not in word_embeddings) or (candidate_word not in word_embeddings):
        return 0.0
    target_vec = word_embeddings[target_word]
    candidate_vec = word_embeddings[candidate_word]
    embedding_arr = np.vstack(word_embeddings.values())

    # Calculate cosine similarity between target word and candidate word
    cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(target_vec, candidate_vec)
    
    # Calculate sum of cosine similarities between target word and all words in the embedding
    # using a vectorized computation
    dp = np.dot(embedding_arr, target_vec)              # dimension (n_words,)
    e_norm = np.linalg.norm(embedding_arr, axis=1)      # dimension (n_words,)
    t_norm = np.linalg.norm(target_vec)                 # dimension 1
    sum_cosine_similarities = (dp / (e_norm * t_norm)).sum()

    # Return normalized cosine_sim
    if sum_cosine_similarities > 0.0:
        return cosine_sim / sum_cosine_similarities
    else:
        return 0.0


Thank you for help.
The code did not reduce computational run time, i interrupted it. it makes it worse. let me share the whole code in GitHub so you could see  the whole code. Here is the link: https://github.com/eyasu11321238a/NTLM-IR-Experiment/blob/main/New_NTLM_Experiment_-Copy__2.ipynb
